# Installing lighthouse - Issues with npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, lighthouse

I'm trying to install lighthouse in the terminal using

```
npm install -g lighthouse
```

But I get the following error.
**Note:** "<user-name" replaces my name

```
(base) X-136:~ <user-name>$ npm install -g lighthouse
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/<user-name>/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/lighthouse
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/<user-name>/.npm"
```

It seems to be that npm is placed under global, which is what is needed. Any advice on what to do?
I have tried to run the sudo code but doesn't do anything.

```
(base) X-136:~ <user-name>$ npm list -g
/Users/<user-name>/.npm-global/lib
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux, you can try with sudo command,

```
sudo npm install -g lighthouse
```

Comment: Hi Shohidul Bari, I did run your code but then when I try to install lighthouse I get the same error

Comment: Okay. Then follow this link, It may help you. https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: Now I get this new message after performing some other changes on permissions:

Comment: '''(base) X-136:~ <user-name>$ npm install -g lighthouse
npm WARN deprecated intl-messageformat-parser@1.8.1: We've written a new parser that's 6x faster and is backwards compatible. Please use @formatjs/icu-messageformat-parser

changed 82 packages, and audited 83 packages in 1s

7 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
'''

Comment: Can you check your node and npm versions? If it is an older one, try to install a newer version.

Comment: Thanks Shohidul Bari! I had an old version. I had to clean all the computer and then install and give privileges.

Answer (score 0):

At the end to solve the issue, I cleaned up the computer and reinstall all again, as an old package was interfering. Then give the correct privileges.